# Add 3 matches to make 6 squares

Tags: geometry, matches

This puzzle appeared at the UQ Mobile store at Shibuya Scramble Square:
[image]

> マッチ棒でできた六角形にマッチ棒を
> 3本追加して正方形を6つ作りなさい
> Add 3 matches to this (a regular hexagon made out of 6 matches) to produce 6 squares.

No other salient information is provided. Can this be solved?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add three matches like this

> [image]
>
>  Now it looks like a cube which has 6 square faces.